# javax.microedition package documentation

Tags: java-me

I have to design a mobile application as my mini project. I cannot find the documentation of javax.microedition in my java folder. I tried searching it online, but all the websites have vague information. I need proper details of this package. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tried searching it online, but all the websites have vague information

Did you try different search engines? I always switch to alternative engine when I feel that one I usually prefer doesn't do the trick.

Don't know if your case but to me results of search for **"javax.microedition package"** were totally different depending on engine. While one engine ("good") gave me a needed link at the top of the very first page, another had it buried at 7th page ("bad", really bad).

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2yOQ.jpg]

Anyway, there's pretty detailed and accurate answer at [SDN Mobility Reference FAQ - J2ME Package Listing](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/packages/index.html):

> **Question**
>
> What package names are defined in the J2ME environment?
>
> **Answer**
>
> The J2ME environment introduces a number of Java packages. These are almost exclusively placed into the package `javax.microedition`. The few exceptions are technologies that could be used in one or more other editions of the Java platform as well. For example, because you might use Bluetooth technology in either J2ME or J2SE, the Java APIs for Bluetooth specification (JSR 82) uses the package names `javax.bluetooth` and `javax.obex`.
>
> The table shows the package names specified by the J2ME JSRs, as defined by the [Java Community Process](http://jcp.org/) (JCP). It includes...

...continue reading at above link if you're interested in more details

Comment: you're welcome. By the way you can also take a look at an "instruction" explaining how we at StackOverflow deal with _helpful_ answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235